# Exception has occurred: TypeError TypeError: connection.queryRaw is not a function

Tags: node.js, node-mssql

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
TypeError: connection.queryRaw is not a function
    at parent.acquire (c:\Users\Dinuka\dev\UpperKothmaleBackEnd\node_modules\mssql\lib\msnodesqlv8.js:458:32)
    at _acquire.then.connection (c:\Users\Dinuka\dev\UpperKothmaleBackEnd\node_modules\mssql\lib\base.js:174:42)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

I am using mssql 4.3 and node 10.13.0
This exception is thrown when I run the code, which includes ConnectionPool.

Please help!

Comment: maybe show the lines of code that caused the problem?

Comment: Please post the code where you're making the connection